# Accessing header params in RestClient API get call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I am doing a RestClient api call to one of my controller as follows:

```
RestClient.get(url,{:secret_key => "abcd"})
```

But when I am printing the params in my controller as follows:

```
p params
```

I cannot find the **secret_key** in the controller. From  https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb#L71 I learnt that header params are passed in RestClient API get call like the above.

But I don't know how to access the header. So if anyone helps me in figuring this out I will be really grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want get secret_key in params hash you can pass this parameter through url string like:

```
url = "http://your.api?secret_key=secret"
RestClient.get(url)
```

or if you want pass secret_key though headers you should:

```
RestClient.get(url, {"secret_key" => "secret"})
```

in rails controller:

```
secret_key = request.headers["secret_key"]
=> "secret"
```

Comment: Rails adds `HTTP_` to the front of the headers so it can be accessed with: `request.headers['HTTP_SECRET_KEY']`

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the header and checking for params..

So, first parameter is params to the request, second is headers

```
RestClient.get url, {:secret_key => "abcd"}, {:user_agent => user_agent}
```

If you only want to send params do

```
RestClient.get url, :params => {:secret_key => "abcd"}
```

If you want to check the response header (`RestClient.get(url,{:secret_key => "abcd"})`) do

```
response['secrect_key']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass http params via url in this way:

```
RestClient.get("http://your.api?secret_key=secret")
```

Answer (score 0):

For my version of rest-client (1.6.7), the signature for RestClient.get specifies HTTP HEADER parameters in the 2nd argument:

```
  def self.get(url, headers={}, &block)
    Request.execute(:method => :get, :url => url, :headers => headers, &block)
  end
```

What I recall for the RestClient.post is that the HTTP HEADER parameters can be specified without braces:

```
RestClient.post(url, :content_type => "application/pdf", :accept => "application/json")
```

I would guess RestClient.get works in a similar fashion.